# ElasticSearch Searching for a phrase

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having a problem understanding how elasticsearch scores among the documents  which contains the specified phrase. 
Consider the mapping - 
[image]

The following data - 
[image]

and when posting the following query -

[image]

I get the following result - 
[image]

Firstly I want to know that how elastic search is giving different scores to the three docs even when they contain the specified  word and what if i want to give more score to the record with _id = 1 i.e.when the user searches for  word 'attendee' then how to give more score to doc with _id = 1 more score.

Comment: You mean to increase the _score for lets say _id=1 for example?

Comment: Yes. If i seach  for  'attendee' then only those doc should have more score where 'attendee' is in isolation and not with some other word like 'matching' or 'featured'